# How to convert a xls file to xml?

Tags: xml, linux, excel, xls

I have an excel file that has multiple work sheets inside it, and each sheet has links to other sheets, I'm currently having trouble converting this file into XML format.
Each worksheet includes information about a hotel including contacts, rates, rooms, policies, etc.
please note I use linux, so I can't run vb.net codes to convert

Answer (score 5):

Save the file as .xlsx, distinguished by Office 2007 and later. .xlsx files are compressed xml files. See more about [Open XML in MS website](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/openup/openxml/default.aspx). You also may use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to develop .Net project under Linux.